# MVC - applying currency format to text box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

In MVC I have the following attribute on my model.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:c2}")]
```

When using DisplayFor this renders as a currency to two decimal places.

However when I use TextBoxFor I get more than two decimal places.

Is there a way to restrict the textbox to two decimal places as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor

Answer (score 0):

As stated EditorFor will work.

In my case I passed the format string into TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentAmount, "{0:0.00}"..........)
```